# Duplicate project with different database username & password

Tags: qgis

I have created a QGIS project that connects to a database using a unique username and password. I need to replicate the project with changes to the username and password. Is there a script that can do that for me?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question but this plugin https://geogear.wordpress.com/2015/09/30/changedatasource-plugin-release-1-0/ ,maybe?

Comment: Version 2.0 of that plugin is also available: https://geogear.wordpress.com/2016/01/29/changedatasourceplugin-plugin-release-2-0/